# Regression trees or Random Forest regressor with categorical inputs

Tags: python, regression, scikit-learn

I have been trying to use a categorical inpust in a regression tree (or Random Forest Regressor) but sklearn keeps returning errors and asking for numerical inputs.

```
import sklearn as sk
MODEL = sk.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
MODEL.fit([('a',1,2),('b',2,3),('a',3,2),('b',1,3)], [1,2.5,3,4]) # does not work
MODEL.fit([(1,1,2),(2,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3)], [1,2.5,3,4]) #works

MODEL = sk.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()
MODEL.fit([('a',1,2),('b',2,3),('a',3,2),('b',1,3)], [1,2.5,3,4]) # does not work
MODEL.fit([(1,1,2),(2,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3)], [1,2.5,3,4]) #works
```

To my understanding, categorical inputs should be possible in these methods without any conversion (e.g. WOE substitution).

Has anyone else had this difficulty?

thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`scikit-learn` has no dedicated representation for categorical variables (a.k.a factors in R), one possible solution is to encode the strings as `int` using `LabelEncoder`:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder  
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

X = np.asarray([('a',1,2),('b',2,3),('a',3,2),('c',1,3)]) 
y = np.asarray([1,2.5,3,4])

# transform 1st column to numbers
X[:, 0] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(X[:,0]) 

regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=150, min_samples_split=2)
regressor.fit(X, y)
print(X)
print(regressor.predict(X))
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 0.  3.  2.]
 [ 2.  1.  3.]]
[ 1.61333333  2.13666667  2.53333333  2.95333333]
```

But remember that this is a slight hack if `a` and `b` are independent categories and it only works with tree-based estimators. Why? Because `b` is not really bigger than `a`. The correct way would be to use the `OneHotEncoder` after the `LabelEncoder` or `pd.get_dummies` yielding two separate, one-hot encoded columns for `X[:, 0]`.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

X = np.asarray([('a',1,2),('b',2,3),('a',3,2),('c',1,3)]) 
y = np.asarray([1,2.5,3,4])

# transform 1st column to numbers
import pandas as pd
X_0 = pd.get_dummies(X[:, 0]).values
X = np.column_stack([X_0, X[:, 1:]])

regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=150, min_samples_split=2)
regressor.fit(X, y)
print(X)
print(regressor.predict(X))
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't think it solves the problem though; the 'numerical labels' create an assumption of a linear progression that will most likely be untrue to what you are trying to predict. Imagine a decision tree node and when deciding the next cut-off split using for example '<2 and >=2' does not make the same sense as "if in ('a','c')".

Comment: I misread your question. I just saw that you want to treat everything as categorical. I will update the example accordingly...

Comment: This helps and I had tried this (with less elegant code I should say), but the problem is that this makes the information contained in the variable less likely to be chosen in a regression tree. I guess this happens because the predictive power is now split across multiple variables. Nevertheless, your code was very helpful in how to do this much more efficiently. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must dummy code by hand in python. I would suggest using [pandas.get_dummies()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) for one hot encoding. For Boosted trees I have had success using [factorize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) to achieve Ordinal Encoding.

There is also a whole package for this sort of thing [here](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/index.html).

For a more detailed explanation look in [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/strings-as-features-in-decision-tree-random-forest) Data Science Stack Exchange post.